# Javascript - Regular Expression with string template followed by 4 digits number?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

Good day. I wanna detect the url string in the `<a>` tag

```
<a href="http://virtualweb.test/en/?post_type=tribe_events&p=3642">Link</a>
```

whether it matchs the pattern : `?post_type=tribe_events&p=####` (#### = 4 digits number)

I'm writing some Jquery code to detect the expression but the console is throwing the error :

> Invalid regular expression: /^(?)post_type=tribe_events&p=^(d{4})/:
>   Invalid group

```
var str = $(a).attr("href");
var regexEx  = /^(?)post_type=tribe_events&p=^(d{4})/;
  var ok = regexEx.exec(str);
  console.log(ok);
```

I'm not good at the regex so I'd be aprreciated if there's any help.

Comment: `(?)` doesn't make sense - there's nothing for the `?` to repeat. Also, `&p=^(d{4})` won't work because what follows `=` definitely won't be at the start of a line

Comment: but I add the ^ before the (?) - which means it matches the ? as the beginning letter

Comment: No, an unescaped `?` means "match one or zero of the preceding token"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of issues in your regex.

- You need to remove `^` from your regex which denotes start of string and in your case your string doesn't actually start from a `?` and is in middle of the string.
- You need to escape `?` as it has special meaning in regex which is zero or one occurrence of a character.
- You need to remove second `^` after `p=` which isn't needed
- You need to write `\d` and not just `d` for representing a number.
- Also you don't need to group `?` and `\d{4}` unless you really need them.

You corrected regex becomes,

```
\?post_type=tribe_events&p=\d{4}
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/T1ekou/1)**

Comment: Thank you for such a clear explanation :D you make my day

Comment: Pleased to help :)

Answer (score 0):

If the test is really what you want, I suppose the right syntax would be:

```
/^\?post_type=tribe_events&p=\d{4}/
```